# Kinematics Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

The question asks me to find the angular velocity.

[image: figure]

Now I do not want you to solve my homework, I want explanation please.

It states that the acceleration of point P is $\vec{a}= -3.02 \vec{i} -1.624 \vec{j}$ when $\theta=60$
It also states that the diameter of the flywheel is 600mm.

My question is :

I know that the acceleration is split into 2 components, tangential and normal.

I know that $a_n=r \alpha$ and $a_t=-r(\omega)^2$.

- Is everything I mentioned until now correct ?
- How can I know which value does an and at take from a given above ?
- How do I decide the i and j terms respectively ?

Again, please do not answer the question and find the angular velocity, but please explain the correct approach and whether my deductions are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the acceleration vector already specified.  You have to separate it into tangentual and radial components, and only **after** you obtain $a_\textrm{t}$ and $a_\textrm{r}$ you use expression $a_\textrm{t} = r \alpha$ and $a_\textrm{r} = r \omega^2$.  Therefore, you can obtain $\alpha$ and $\omega$ of the flywheel.

You can separate $\vec{a} = a_x \vec{i} + a_y \vec{j}$ by multiplying it (by virtue of scalar product) with unit vectors for the point position

$$a_\textrm{r} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{e_\textrm{r}}, a_\textrm{t} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{e_\textrm{t}},$$ with

$$\vec{e_\textrm{r}} = \cos(\theta) \vec{i} + \sin(\theta) \vec{j}, \vec{e_\textrm{t}} = - \sin(\theta) \vec{i} + \cos(\theta) \vec{j}.$$ 
.

Comment: When you say ar=a*er, where er=cos(th)i + sign(th)j ... does that mean I have to multiply the i-component in a with the i component of er ? and similarly to j ?

Comment: Yes.  When you do scalar product of two vectors, it eventually comes to multiplying its components, e.g. $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = a_x b_x + a_y b_y$.  But that is already mathematics.

Comment: One more question please, why is er=+cos +sin while et= +cos -sin ... did you take i to the right and j upwards ? or another convention ?

Comment: The choice of $\vec{e}_\text{r}$ and $\vec{e}_\text{t}$ comes from the polar (cylindrical) coordinate system ($r, \theta$).  See, for example, picture No. 15 on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system.  It just happens that unit vector $\hat{r} = \vec{e}_\text{r}$ always point in the direction of radial acceleration and unit vector $\hat{\theta} = \vec{e}_\text{t}$ always in the direction of tangential acceleration, regardless of $\theta$ and $r$.  To get radial and tangential part of acceleration, you just have to multiply it with these unit vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have been trying to solve that now but with no avail, the answer keeps coming out wrong. Can you further explain how I get to choose the correct angle for cos and sin and relative position in terms of i and j ? I know ar always points along the radius r of 300mm, and at is tangent (90 degrees) to that r. However how does this affect the solving ? I think I'm getting confused with the whole coordinates system.

Comment: *sigh*  We have two problems: first it is almost impossible to explain it without draw the problem on paper and second I think you have problems with mathematics and not physics.  All I can do is to give you step by step result and hope for the best.  $a_\text{r} = a_x \cos(\theta)+a_y \sin(\theta)$, $a_\text{t} = - a_x \sin(\theta)+a_y \cos(\theta)$, $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{a_\text{r}}{r}}$, $\alpha = \frac{a_\text{t}}{r}$, $a_x=−3.02, a_y=−1.624, \theta=60$.  Note the angle is in degrees.

Comment: I have found w before and it was correct, and I had everything correct as you posted EXCEPT for at, which was needed for the second part to find angular acceleration. My mistake was having at=cos(th)i + sin(th)j instead of the opposite way around (although you have posted that in your answer, my bad). And yes I agree with you, I have a weakness in mathematics. Can I ask for one last favor, can you sketch a quick diagram with at and ar and indicate how did you choose the cosine and sine terms, I just need to refresh my mind regarding this topic, been a while since I covered it. Regards.

Comment: Here I have attached my sketch, can you confirm if I got it down right ? Shouldnt ar=-cos(th)-sin(th) since ar is pointing to the left and down ? http://imageshack.us/a/img577/194/imagenyn.jpg

Comment: $\vec{e}_\text{r} = \hat{r}$ is pointing right - up.  But $a_\text{r}$ you've calculated is most probably negative, so $\vec{a}_\text{r} = a_\text{r} \vec{e}_\text{r}$ is pointing left - down.  Multiplying vector with negative value flips its direction.

Comment: Looking at your drawing, I realized what is the problem.  Unit vector $\hat{r}$ always points out, while $\vec{a}_\text{r}$ always points in.  But I think this is acceptable, because you **have** to use unit vectors of polar coordinate system to calculate acceleration components.  This is the most straightforward way for calculation.

Comment: Thanks for replying, so how come using the what I deduced from this whole discussion to solve for angular acceleration yields the incorrect answer ? If I use the same exact method to solve for ar, I get w=3.2rad/s which is correct. But if I use the same method to find at, I get alpha=5.56 -- but apparently the correct answer is 6.12rad/s^2 ... I have found ar=2.918m/s^2 and at=1.6705m/s^2. Im not sure what im doing wrong.

Comment: Hm, I got $a_\textrm{r} = 2.9, a_\textrm{t} = 1.8$ and thus $\omega = 2.2, \alpha = 3.0$

Comment: Thanks for replying Pygmalion, but apparently the answer is ω=3.12rad/s , α=6.01rad/s^2 according the answer sheet ... Im not getting that answer though !

Comment: Oh yes... **diameter** $d = 0.6$, so radius $r= 0.3$, so I get 3.1 and 6.0 too.

Comment: I have no idea what im doing wrong to be honest, I cant get the answer....can you provide me with a picture of your solution ? I would like to know your approach to solving this.

Answer (score 0):

For your reference working backwards, if the acceleration of the origin is zero then the acceleration at *P* is

$$ \vec{a}_P = \vec{\alpha}\times\vec{r}_P + \vec{\omega}\times(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_P) $$

where $\vec{r}_P = r\cos(\theta) \hat{i} + r \sin(\theta) \hat{j} $, $\vec{\omega}=\omega \hat{k}$ and $\vec{\alpha}=\alpha \hat{k}$. Then you equate the left hand side components (known) with the right hand side for the unknown $\omega$ and $\alpha$.

Note $\times$ is the vector cross product. Projected into the *xy*-plane these are

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\  \alpha \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -y \,\alpha \\ x \,\alpha \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

and

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\  \omega \end{pmatrix} \times \left( \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\  \omega \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right) = \begin{pmatrix} -x \,\omega^2 \\ -y \,\omega^2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

making the above vector equation into a planar one

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a_x \\ a_y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -y \, \alpha \\ x\,\alpha \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -x \, \omega^2 \\ -y \,\omega^2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: This is a good answer, and more physical one, the only problem is that it is mathematically much more complex to solve (vector product and double vector product).

Comment: I agree. So I edited the answer with the planar projection of the cross products to make constructing the answer easier.